# SSRS Checking whether dataset returned erroneous rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a dataset that calls a stored procedure in an SSRS report. If the dataset has no rows, it returns a different set of fields than when it has rows.  This causes all of the fields to display `#ERROR`.

Is there a way to check if the dataset is returning the appropriate fields, so I can hide the dataset rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question

The solution for this is to check the IsMissing property on the dataset field:

Set the row's "Hidden" property to -

=IIF(Fields!FieldThatShouldBeThere.IsMissing,true,false)

Frank